# UIImagePickerController alternative that support multi-select and moment view

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, elcimagepickercontroller

I know that UIImagePickerController is not support multi-select so i tried some alternatives:
ELCImagePickerController, WSAssetPickerController and CTAssetsPickerController.

All of them support the multi-select feature, but i also need the "Moments" view as in the UIImagePickerController :

[image]

Is there any library that support multi-select and "Moments" view?

Answer (score 4):

Try [GMImagePicker](https://github.com/guillermomuntaner/GMImagePicker). It uses the new Photos framework (PhotoKit) which gives you access to iOS 8's photo hierarchy. You're going to have to customize it a bit, though.

In Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html):

> Use the PHCollectionList class to find assets corresponding to the
>   Moments hierarchy in the Photos App

So somewhere around [here](https://github.com/guillermomuntaner/GMImagePicker/blob/master/GMImagePicker/GMAlbumsViewController.m#L98) you'll want to call one of the `fetchCollectionLists` functions like [`fetchCollectionListsWithType:subtype:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHCollectionList_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHCollectionList/fetchCollectionListsWithType:subtype:options:) with type `PHCollectionListTypeMomentList`. You'll have another `PHFetchResult` to treat as an album the way the author does [here](https://github.com/guillermomuntaner/GMImagePicker/blob/master/GMImagePicker/GMAlbumsViewController.m#L140).

If I have time I'll edit this with a more thorough answer, but I think it'll be fun and educational to learn the Photos framework and work on this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://github.com/uzysjung/UzysAssetsPickerController). I can't immediately see if it supports moments, but give it a go.

You might also be interested in [this article](http://www.objc.io/issue-21/the-photos-framework.html) from objc.io on the Photos Framework

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't support "Moments"